Can someone help me understand how a scene is recalled on the hue v2 api?
I found this post and I have my scene id but I don’t understand how I activate that scene on a specific group or zone.  I have the same scene in a few different zones so how do I activate it on just that one zone?
I can get all of the information I need from the v2 api
Activating a scene for a room or a zone using Philips Hue API V2
Here’s what I have so far
import requests
import json
import urllib3

# Disable SSL warnings if using a self-signed certificate
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

class HueAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = "https://my ip"
        self.headers = {
            "User-Agent": "HTTPBot/2024.1.3",
            "hue-application-key": my key"
        }

    def resource_route(self, endpoint):
        """Builds and returns the full URL for the given endpoint."""
        return f"{self.base_url}/{endpoint}"

    def get_data(self, url):
        """Fetches data from the given URL."""
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, verify=False)
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching data: {e}")
            return None

    def get_zone_id(self, zone_name):
        """Fetches the zone ID for a given zone name."""
        url = self.resource_route("clip/v2/resource/zone")
        json_data = self.get_data(url)
        if json_data:
            for item in json_data.get('data', []):
                if item['metadata']['name'] == zone_name:
                    return item['id'], item['type']
        return None, None

    def get_scene_id(self, scene_name):
        """Fetches the scene ID for a given scene name."""
        url = self.resource_route("clip/v2/resource/scene")
        json_data = self.get_data(url)
        if json_data:
            for item in json_data.get('data', []):
                if item['metadata']['name'] == scene_name:
                    print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))
                    return item['id']
        return None

    def post_scene_data(self, resource_name, scene_name, action):
        """Posts the scene data to the API."""
        action_bool = action.lower() == "on"
        resource_id, resource_type = self.get_zone_id(resource_name)  # Use self to call instance methods
        scene_id = self.get_scene_id(scene_name)  # Use self to call instance methods

        if resource_id and scene_id:
            scene_payload = {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "scene",
                    "id": scene_id,
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "target": {
                                "rid": resource_id,
                                "rtype": resource_type
                            },
                            "action": {
                                "on": {
                                    "on": action_bool
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }

            url = self.resource_route("clip/v2/resource/scene")
            print(self.headers)
            print(url)
            try:
                response = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, verify=False, json=scene_payload)
                response.raise_for_status()
                return response.json()
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(f"Error posting data: {e}")
                return None
        else:
            print("Resource or scene ID not found.")
            return None

